# Is every non-zero additive function injective/surjective?

Tags: functional-equations

An additive function is a function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, for all real $x$ and $y$. Aside from the identically $0$ function, is every such function injective/surjective? Certainly, every additive function of the form $cx$ for some nonzero constant $c$ is a bijective function. So, an equivalent way of asking my question is, is every "pathological" additive function injective/surjective? If not all of them, then are at least some pathological additive functions injective/surjective?

Comment: [Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492)

Comment: Some answers in comments here: [Is the function from the Cauchy functional equation, $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ injective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657253) To summarize: using a Hamel $\Bbb Q$-basis of $\Bbb R$ (hence relying on AC), it is extremely easy to construct uncountably many "wild" solutions which are idempotent hence neither injective nor surjective, but also uncountably many "wild" [involutive (hence bijective) solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953943).